# Android Bluetooth java.io.IOException: Connection refused?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I need to connect a [KwikBlue-2 Module Development Kit](http://www.socketmobile.com/products/embedded-wireless-communications/kwikblue4-module/) to the Android [BluetoothChat example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html) on a Nexus One using SPP.
I was able to connect and exchange serial data (once) using tera term after changing the UUID in the [BluetoothChat example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html) example to 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB for SPP devices.
Then I power cycled the [KwikBlue-2 Module Development Kit](http://www.socketmobile.com/products/embedded-wireless-communications/kwikblue4-module/) to verify that the connection was repeatable but continually get 
`java.io.IOException: Connection refused` when I try to connect.
Any ideas?

```
43.200: ERROR/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(96): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Adapter:PropertyChanged from /org/bluez/219/hci0
52.200: ERROR/BluetoothChat(707): - ON PAUSE -
54.470: ERROR/BluetoothService.cpp(96): stopDiscoveryNative: D-Bus error in StopDiscovery: org.bluez.Error.Failed (Invalid discovery session)
54.520: ERROR/BluetoothChat(707): + ON RESUME +
54.530: ERROR/BluetoothService.cpp(96): stopDiscoveryNative: D-Bus error in StopDiscovery: org.bluez.Error.Failed (Invalid discovery session)
54.620: ERROR/BluetoothService.cpp(96): stopDiscoveryNative: D-Bus error in StopDiscovery: org.bluez.Error.Failed (Invalid discovery session)
55.520: ERROR/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(96): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Device:PropertyChanged from /org/bluez/219/hci0/dev_00_60_57_FD_42_18
56.010: ERROR/BluetoothChatService(707): unable to connect
56.010: ERROR/BluetoothChatService(707): java.io.IOException: Connection refused
56.010: ERROR/BluetoothChatService(707):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connectNative(Native Method)
56.010: ERROR/BluetoothChatService(707):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:204)
56.010: ERROR/BluetoothChatService(707):     at com.cti.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChatService$ConnectThread.run(BluetoothChatService.java:329)
00.110: ERROR/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(96): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Device:PropertyChanged from /org/bluez/219/hci0/dev_00_60_57_FD_42_18
```

Comment: Shot in the dark - have you checked if the kit and the Nexus One are still paired after you power cycled?

Comment: Yes. Still paired, just not connected.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try unpair/repair and then it may work once again. This seems to be a bug with the core Bluetooth support on Android.

Comment: This actually worked. Thanks a million. Don't know why someone downvoted this answer.

Comment: This is not a good answer because it gives no permanent solution to the problem. I have the same issue right now, and cannot tell my users to unpair/pair the app twice a day or more.

Comment: @GlennBech And yet until someone else finds a better solution, it is the only answer.