# Service discovery failed exception in Android Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, client-server

Trying to solve this issue for last 2 days.I see many solutions of this topic in this forum and try most of them like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091913/android-bluetooth-connection-service-discovery-failed) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397071/service-discovery-failed-exception-using-bluetooth-on-android),but sill no luck.For this reason i ask a new question regarding this topic.So anybody could guide me how i can resolve this?Specially i think i can't use the right UUID(though i used the standard UUID of **00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB**) for connecting my **Server PC**(written in java) and **client Android**.

**Server Code(Java):**

```
public class Main {


    private final LocalDevice mLocalDevice;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        new Main().start();
    }

    public Main() throws IOException
    {
        mLocalDevice = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
        mLocalDevice.setDiscoverable(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC);
    }

    public void start() throws IOException
    {
        StreamConnectionNotifier connectionNotifier =(StreamConnectionNotifier) Connector.open("btspp://localhost:" +
                                                                 "0000110100001000800000805F9B34FB;name=BtExample;" +
                                                                     "authenticate=false;encrypt=false;master=false");

        System.out.println("accepting on " + mLocalDevice.getBluetoothAddress());
        StreamConnection streamConnection = connectionNotifier.acceptAndOpen();
        DataInputStream is = streamConnection.openDataInputStream();

        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        int r;
        while ((r = is.read(bytes)) > 0)
        {
             System.out.println(new String(bytes, 0, r));
        }
        streamConnection.close();
    }

}
```

**Client Code(Android):**

```
    try {
        mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        Log.d("BT", "getting local device");
          // remote MAC here:
        BluetoothDevice device =mBtAdapter.getRemoteDevice("My_Computer_bluetooth_Address");
        Log.d("BT", "remote device: "+ device.getName().toString());
        Log.d("BT", "connecting to service");

        //Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c 'sdptool records " + device.getAddress() + "'");
        //Log.d("BT", process.toString());
        //Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
        //socket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);//I also tried this,but same exception occurs
        //sock=socket;
        BluetoothSocket socket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
            UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
        Log.d("BT", "about to connect");

        mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        socket.connect();
        Log.d("BT", "Connected!");

        socket.getOutputStream().write("Hello, world!".getBytes());

} catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("BT", "Error connecting to device", e);
}
```

**Logcat Exception Views:**

```
02-15 14:12:02.022: D/BT(4798): getting local device
02-15 14:12:02.023: D/BT(4798): remote device: SHUVRO-PC    //my PC name
02-15 14:12:02.023: D/BT(4798): connecting to service
02-15 14:12:02.024: I/BluetoothSocket_MTK(4798): [JSR82] Bluetooth Socket Constructor
02-15 14:12:02.024: I/BluetoothSocket_MTK(4798): [JSR82] type=1 fd=-1 auth=false encrypt=false port=-1
02-15 14:12:02.026: D/BT(4798): about to connect
02-15 14:12:02.055: I/BluetoothSocket_MTK(4798): [JSR82] connect: do SDP
02-15 14:12:08.057: I/BluetoothSocket_MTK(4798): [JSR82] SdpHelper::onRfcommChannelFound: channel=-1
02-15 14:12:08.059: E/BT(4798): Error connecting to device
02-15 14:12:08.059: E/BT(4798): java.io.IOException: Service discovery failed
02-15 14:12:08.059: E/BT(4798):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket$SdpHelper.doSdp(BluetoothSocket.java:813)
02-15 14:12:08.059: E/BT(4798):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:382)
02-15 14:12:08.059: E/BT(4798):     at com.bluetoothTest.BluetoothTestActivity.onClick(BluetoothTestActivity.java:82)
02-15 14:12:08.059: E/BT(4798):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3517)
02-15 14:12:08.059: E/BT(4798):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14155)
02-15 14:12:08.059: E/BT(4798):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-15 14:12:08.059: E/BT(4798):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-15 14:12:08.059: E/BT(4798):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-15 14:12:08.059: E/BT(4798):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4508)
02-15 14:12:08.059: E/BT(4798):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-15 14:12:08.059: E/BT(4798):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-15 14:12:08.059: E/BT(4798):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
02-15 14:12:08.059: E/BT(4798):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
02-15 14:12:08.059: E/BT(4798):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I have a similar problem. Any clue to solve this ?

Comment: No,not yet,i stopped that work as i can't get rid of it!If you find let me know..

Comment: @ben75: Same prob here.Did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code I use on the client side to establish a (secure or unsecure) connection. In my use case : a non-trivial pinCode means that the target device requires a secure connection, otherwise the target device accept an unsecure connection.

I think this code requires API-level 15+

```
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
public final String BT_UUID = "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB";
private BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;
private BluetoothSocket socket;

...

public void establishBluetoothConnection(String pinCode) throws IOException {
    //needed because "bluetooth device discovery" may initiated by any other
    // process and there are good chances that the socket.connect() fail when bluetooth discovery process is running.
    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery(); 

    if ("".equals(pinCode) || pinCode == null || "0000".equals(pinCode)) {
        socket = bluetoothDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString(BT_UUID));
    } else {
        setPin(pinCode);
        socket = bluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString(BT_UUID));
    }
    socket.connect(); //blocking up to timeout of about 12 sec. throws IOException in case of failure
}



/**
 * hack to set the pin code programatically. The android API don't have a public method to set the pin code.
 * that's why we use this hack. In case of failure: android will prompt the user to enter the pin code manually.
 */
private void setPin(String pinCode) {
    try {
        byte[] ar = pinCode.getBytes();
        Method m2 = bluetoothDevice.getClass().getMethod("setPin", new Class[]{byte[].class});
        m2.invoke(bluetoothDevice, ar);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        Log.e("Bluetooth", "Failed to set pin code", e);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        Log.e("Bluetooth", "Failed to set pin code", e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        Log.e("Bluetooth", "Failed to set pin code", e);
    }
}
```